# Array taking up waay too much memory

Tags: php, arrays, memory

I am creating an array to hold values returned from a query - It seems adding to a multi dimensional array causes the script to take upto 125Mb of memory and considering the total amount of data that the array is supposed to hold is not more than 5Mb it's very weird:

Here is what I am doing:

```
try 
{
    if (!$link = mysql_connect(DB_Host, DB_User, DB_Password))
            Throw New Exception(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_select_db("Spexplus_Demo"))
            throw New Exception(mysql_error());
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage().$e->getTraceAsString();
    exit(1);
}

$query = "select cda.categoryid as categoryId, 
                  cda.templatetype as templateType, 
                  hn.headerid as headerId, 
                  hn.name as headerName, 
                  an.attributeid as attributeId, 
                  an.name as attributeName
                  from categorydisplayattributes cda 
                  join categoryheader ch on cda.headerid = ch.headerid 
                  and cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype 
                  and cda.categoryid = ch.categoryid 
                  join headernames hn on cda.headerid = hn.headerid 
                  and hn.localeid = 1
                  join attributenames an on cda.attributeid = an.attributeid 
                  and an.localeid = 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

        {
            $categorydisplayattributes[$row['categoryId']][$row['templateType']][$row['headerId']][$row['headerName']][$row['attributeId']][$row['attributeName']] =array() ;
        }


echo "Memory After CDA:".memory_get_usage(TRUE).Line_Terminator;
exit();
```

The query result itself doesn't go beyond 5Mb or so when I check, however, assigning the values to the array in this fashion causes the spike - Has anyone else encountered something like this?

Comment: My very blind guess would be that it's just because it's a 6 dimensional hash table.

Comment: try use ini_set('memory_limit', '512M') to add you memory

Comment: http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html the ling tell you How big are PHP arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))


           {

//concatenate the values using '.' if string 

$index = $row['categoryId']][$row['templateType']][$row['headerId']][$row['headerName']][$row['attributeId']][$row['attributeName'];

                $categorydisplayattributes[$index] =array() ;
            }
```

try that.

Comment: Down to ~ half but still very high - would / should Arrays typically require this much memory?

Comment: how long the index is + how much the array size is ? if you can think of split it into chunks will increase performance and memeory too. if you can paste a sample of output would help think deeper

Comment: `array(1082) { [10200]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [35]=> array(1) { ["General Information"]=> array(10) { [3411896]=> array(1) { ["Manufacturer"]=> array(0) { } } [341450]=> array(1) { ["Manufacturer Part Number"]=> array(0) { } } [341451]=> array(1) { ["Manufacturer Website Address"]=> array(0) { } } [34113319]=> array(1) { ["Brand Name"]=> array(0) { } } [3412389]=> array(1) { ["Product Line"]=> array(0) { } }`

This is a sample of the array - The reason I am doing it in this manner is that I need to keep the order intact

Comment: if that is the case i think try make a temporary table and insert the above records in that with a index key then query the table with index as key that will save php array to hold this temp data